# __autoload куда инклюдит файлы?

Tags: php

обычно когда пишем include то подразумеваем что в том месте где написали туда и воткнется код из файла

а что происходит с `__autoload` ?
куда он вставляет файлы?

а если использовать?

```
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:

вот допустим вызывается класс `new User()`

ну ок допустим автолоад присабачил файл перед этим вызовом, но потом допустим в другом классе снова вызывается `new User()` допустим даже в другой области видимости, и что автолоад повторно присабачивает файл?

это не эффективно если так

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2:

А вот допустим вызов `spl_autoload_register()` лежит в одном классе а сама функция в другом

Куда тогда будет инклюдится файл?

В то место где вызывается функция `spl_autoload_register()` или в самой функции где прописан инклюд?

Answer (score 1):

spl_autoload_register() имеет своим аргументом функцию в которой написано `include` или `include_once` (на самом деле что угодно, лишь бы класс после этого появился), при вызове new User();  вызовется эта самая функция и в том месте где у нее строчка `include()`  там и состоится ваш include.

Далее читаем мануал по include, чтобы понять, что происходит при этом на самом деле. (хинт - классы глобально объявляются, или в namespace)

Comment: дописал наверху дополнение 2

Comment: запуск инклюда состоится в callback функции, как работает инклюд - в документации почитайте. (еще хинт - php обычно однотредовый)

Comment: вообще вы подумайте, чем include в этом случае может отличаться от обычного include - ответ - ничем. Но в функции может и не быть include, там может быть например eval, или include и eval, или еще какой-нить способ создания класса.